# Auto deploying war file in ManageEngine servicedesk

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jboss

I am in a middle of a penetration testing , I have created a war file and I am trying to Auto Deploy it in manageengine's Service desk plus. My question is

1. When I put the war file in

> C:\ManageEngine\ServiceDesk\server\default\deploy\

it is automatically deployed to

> c:\ManageEngine\ServiceDesk\server\default\tmp\deploy\tmp2724browser.war\

1. Is there any way I can make it deploy in the folder where manageengine's applications are extracted so that I can access it through url or is there any way I can access this file by changing the context.xml

also there is server.xml file in a server folder as follows :

```
<Server>

   <!-- Use a custom version of StandardService that allows the
   connectors to be started independent of the normal lifecycle
   start to allow web apps to be deployed before starting the
   connectors.
   -->
   <Service name="jboss.web"
      className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.StandardService">

      <!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
      <!-- The compression parameters are taken from the default Tomcat server.xml-->
      <Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
         maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
         connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
         compression="on"
         compressionMinSize="2048"
         URIEncoding="UTF-8"
         noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
         compressableMimeType="text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,text/plain,text/html"/>

         <!-- setBodyEncodingForURI="true" -->

 <!-- A AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<!--
      <Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" debug="0"
         protocol="AJP/1.3"/>
 -->

      <!-- SSL/TLS Connector configuration using the admin devl guide keystore
      <Connector port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="15"
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
           keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/sdp.keystore"
           keystorePass="sdpsecured" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
      -->

      <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost">

         <!-- The JAAS based authentication and authorization realm implementation
            - certificatePrincipal : the class name of the
            org.jboss.security.auth.certs.CertificatePrincipal impl
            used for mapping X509[] cert chains to a Princpal.
         -->
         <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
            certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
            />

         <Logger className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.Log4jLogger"
            verbosityLevel="INFORMATION"
            category="org.jboss.web.localhost.Engine"/>

         <Host name="localhost"
            autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false">

            <!-- Uncomment to enable request dumper. This Valve "logs interesting
                 contents from the specified Request (before processing) and the
                 corresponding Response (after processing). It is especially useful
                 in debugging problems related to headers and cookies."
            -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve" />
            -->

            <!-- Access logger -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
               pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log"
               resolveHosts="false" />
            -->


            <!-- Uncomment to check for unclosed connections in servlets/jsps
            <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve"
                cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager" />
            -->
          <!--
          * Various Patterns and its meaning
                         %u - Remote user that was authenticated (if any), else '-'
                         %U - Requested URL path
                         %S - User session ID
                         %{Referer}i  - Referer for the web resource
                         %a - Remote IP address
                         %A - Local IP address
                         %m - Request method (GET, POST, etc.)
                         %t - Date and time, in Common Log Format
                         %D - Time taken to process the request, in millis
                         %b - Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers, or '-' if zero
                         %s - HTTP status code of the response
                         %{User-Agent}i - Browser , platform , robot info ...
               -->
           <!--
           <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
               pattern="%u %U %{JSESSIONIDSSO}c &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; %a %A %m %t %D %b %s &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;"
               directory="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log"/>
        -->
        <!-- Access logger -->
        <!--
            * The default logger as packaged with the Tomcat version. If you do not want all the
            * information that is being logged (as defined in the previous valve), comment out the
            * earlier one and uncomment the following definition
        -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
            prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
            pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log"
            resolveHosts="false" />
        -->
            <!-- Uncomment to enable single sign-on across web apps
               deployed to this host. Does not provide SSO across a cluster.
            -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" debug="0"/>
        <Valve className="com.adventnet.servicedesk.tools.AuthenticateNtlm" debug="0"/>
             <Valve className="com.adventnet.client.util.LoginParameters" />

                     <!-- This interceptor is added by 'AAA' team, in order to associate
             the caller principal in to the thread that is wroking for the request. -->
                     <Valve className="com.adventnet.authentication.CredentialAssociation"/>

            <!-- Default context parameters -->
        <DefaultContext cookies="true" crossContext="true" override="true"/>

        <!--
        static context 'help' added. The general product document can be placed in this folder
        for easy access
        -->
           <Context path="/help" appBase=""
           docBase="${jboss.home.dir}/help/"
                   debug="99" reloadable="true">
       </Context>
       <Context path="/custom" appBase=""
           docBase="${jboss.home.dir}/custom/"
                   debug="9" reloadable="true">
           </Context>
       <Context path="/inlineimages" appBase=""
           docBase="${jboss.home.dir}/inlineimages/"
                   debug="9" reloadable="true">
       </Context>
       <Context path="/archive" appBase=""
           docBase="${jboss.home.dir}/archive/"
                   debug="9" reloadable="true">
       </Context>
       <!--
       <Context path="/log" appBase=""
           docBase="${jboss.home.dir}/server/default/log/"
                   debug="9" reloadable="true">
       </Context>
       -->

         </Host>

      </Engine>

   </Service>
```

Limitations is that I am only able to upload the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the contents of your war to a folder 'test' in [SDP Home] directory.

Add the following to server.xml present in [SDP Home]/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat50.sar directory.

```
<Context path="/test" appBase="" docBase="${jboss.home.dir}/test/" debug="9" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

Restart the SDP server and connect to [ http: //hostname:portno/test] to access your test application.